# VSE - A strip with a PNG/transp won't show as long as there's another one above it

Tags: video-sequence-editor

As the screenshots show, each strip has a PNG image with transparency. 
blueoutline.png is above yellowball.png, each is using Alpha Over as a method of blending.
What am I missing?
Is this the reason: "Blender won't handle an alpha channel in a codec. Alpha in a codec is largely a nonstandard practice" [Source](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101338/15508).
[image: PNG #1]
[image: PNG #2]

Comment: If you render that frame does it show the Blue ring over the Yellow circle? Also try hitting the "Refresh Sequencer" button.

Answer (score 2):

You want to select both strips and add a [alpha over](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/effects/alpha_over_under_overdrop.html) effect strip. [image]